# Domain and subdomains under one IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache2, subdomain, ubuntu-18.04

I have a goal to host few websites as subdomains.(Apache2 at Ubuntu 18.04 at Google Cloud Platform)
Directories:

`/var/www/domain.com/public_html`- main directory for real registered domain

my subdomains

`/var/www/test1.domain.com/public_html`

`/var/www/test2.domain.com/public_html`

`/var/www/test3.domain.com/public_html`

Access to subdomains by address **test(1,2,3).domain.com**

I'm new with Apache2 so it's possibe I want something unreal or use Apache2 in wrong way. If so could you show my mistakes?

I tried to configure Virtual hosts but unsuccessful.
Maybe it is possible make it via **htaccess**?

`domain.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@mail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`test1.domain.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@mail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test1.domain.com/public_html
    ServerName test1.domain.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What problem are you having - actual request and error messages? How did you enable the virtual hosts? A lot more details are required in your question. Edit your question instead of posting comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble was not in Apache configuration. It was correct. 
If you will have the same goal as mine, first of all you need

- create subdomains at your domain registrar
- create new A records under main domain in cloud DNS for each subdomain(Google Cloud Platform in my case)
- wait (half hour in my case)

And only then configure Apache webserver.